# How do Barton (Hawkeye/Ronin) and Romanov (Black Widow) end up on the Benatar on Morag in 2014?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the scene in *Avengers: Endgame* stated as "Morag 2014", we see Hawkeye/Ronin and Black Widow take off on the Benatar.  The scene is a replica of the opening scene from GotG I, where Quill lands on Morag to grab "the Power Orb", later to find out its the Power Stone.

However, if I'm not mistaken, the Benatar doesn't even exist yet because it was a restoration of the ship (the Milano....?) that got destroyed when Ronan's ship crashes on Xandar.

So in Endgame, how do Barton and Romanov end up flying the Benatar, a ship which hasn't been built yet, to Vormir?

Comment: The *Benatar* (not *Benetar*) wasn't a restoration of the *Milano*, it was the ship the GotG used after [leaving the crashed *Milano* on the planet Berhert (in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2)](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Benatar). Quill's ships are named for women he had crushes on as a boy in the 1980's (Pat Benatar, Alyssa Milano).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Because they brought it with them.

Before going on the Time Heist, they shrunk it down and we see it in Hawkeye's hand

[image: Hawkeye with the tiny Benatar]

> As the Power Stone and Soul Stone were off Earth, the Benatar traveled back to 2014, first dropping off Nebula and War Machine on Morag before Hawkeye and Black Widow used it to travel to Vormir.

Source: [Benatar > History > Used by the Avengers (3rd Paragraph)](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Benatar#Used_by_the_Avengers)

Comment: oh snap... the miniaturization of the Benetar???  I hadn't considered that since Lang's suit appears to be "malfunctioning" right after getting spit out of the quantum tunnel in Endgame, and I'd assume any devices he had would also not work.  Interesting they didnt actually mention that...

Comment: and I always thought that was, like, a car key to the ship...

Comment: Rocket even says "You promise to bring that back in one piece, right?" and Clint's like "yeah,yeah, I'll try"

Comment: @enorl76 It's a bit of a callback to the Antman movies, where they actually had "miniaturized" cars as keychains :P It's one of the small bonuses of having watched all of the movies in the MCU.

Comment: @enorl76 Whatever problems Lang was having with his suit, they appear to have been taken care of by this point, as he uses his shrinking/growing powers quite a few times in the movie.  Granted, mostly on himself, but whatever.  He's got both Stark and Banner around who could probably have fixed him up in between working on the time machine thing.

Comment: I like to think Lang fixed the suit himself. We see him do quite a bit of work on it in the first Ant-Man film, he's got a Masters' in EE after all.

Comment: @DanDoubleL A Masters in EE and a quarter will get you a gob stopper, but probably won't let you fix magical shrinking technology.

Comment: @Yakk A quarter of what? Gob stopper? You're saying an M.E.Eng. degree's not worth the shrapnel for a piece of candy, right?

Comment: @tjt263 A quarter is the colloquial name for a US 25 cent coin (as it is worth 1/4th of a dollar).

Comment: There's no particular, ahem, time pressure at this point, so the Avengers have plenty of days/weeks/months/years to perfect the miniaturization technology before heading through the time tunnel.